# Android custom dialog dismiss() redraws the box

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have accept and reject button, both to dismiss the dialog box. I also have a condition where the dialog will be removed if there is no action by the user, but it is redrawn after being removed. Upon thorough investigation I found out the dialog box was redrawn right after it is removed. This is my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            builder.setView(dialoglayout);
            builder.setTitle("REQUEST");
            builder.setMessage("Would you like to accept?");
            //builder.show();
            dia = builder.create();
            dia.show();

            spRequest.play(spSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1);
               new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       dia.dismiss();
                   }
               }, 7000);    //the alert will play for 7 seconds and stop
            //dia.show();

            Button accept = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.bAcceptRequest);
            accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //mDialog.cancel();
                    dia.dismiss();
                    spRequest.release();
                }
            });

            Button reject = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.bDeclineRequest);
            reject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //mDialog.cancel();
                    Log.e("caution", "dismiss reached");
                    dia.dismiss();
                    spRequest.release();
                }
            });
```

And this is my custom dialog xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_layout_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_dialog_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bAcceptRequest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/acceptrequest"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDeclineRequest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/rejectrequest"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Can someone explain to why the dialog is being redrawn and how to stop that behavior?

Comment: it reappears once or if you close it it will reopen again and again?

Comment: I think you should remove your handler callback after pressing buttons,,, but could you please tell more about what's your problem?

Comment: It appears to me that I have two layers, when push each button it will close the dialog but there is another one redrawn/existing. When I click outside the dialog box it would be removed. I hope I am clear.